# Como retornar materiais de um produto ou níveis do produto com PL/SQL

Tags: sql, pl-sql, dados-hierárquicos

Tenho uma tabela que contém produtos e cada produto tem outros produtos que são usados para fabricar. Os produtos que são usados para fabricar o produto pai, podem ser fabricados também e conter outros produtos fabricados.EX:

```
ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL   PRODUCTION   ID_MATERIAL
1                     2            2
1                     2            3
1                     2            4
2                     1            9
2                     1            10
3                     1            8
8                     1            5
```

O produto 1 precisa dos produtos 2,3 e 4, mas o produto 2 e 3 também são fabricados. O produto 2 precisa do 9 e 10 e o 3 precisa do 8 e por fim o 8 precisa do 5. No caso temos níveis aqui, o produto 1 está no nível 1, os produtos 2,3 e 4 estão no nível 2 e o produto 8 está no nível 3. Eu tentei utilizar hierarquia de níveis com recursividade para fazer o select, mas acontece que não é bem uma hierarquia.
SELECT utilizado abaixo me retorna o seguinte erro:

`Erro de SQL: ORA-32044: Ciclo detectado ao executar a consulta WITH recursiva`

```
WITH CTE (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL,PRODUCTION,ID_MATERIAL) AS (
  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL,
  PRODUCTION,
  ID_MATERIAL,
  FROM MATERIAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL,
  M.PRODUCTION,
  M.ID_MATERIAL,
  FROM MATERIAL M
  INNER JOIN CTE C
  ON M.ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL = C.ID_MATERIAL
  )
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

As colunas ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL e ID_MATERIAL são derivadas da tabela products. Como proceder nesse caso?
Segue a estrutura das tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(
  ID_PRODUCT NUMBER(6,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(200),
  WEIGHT NUMBER(6,2),
  PRICE NUMBER(6,2)
 );

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTION(
  ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION NUMBER(6,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  PRODUCTION NUMBER(3,0),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTIONPRODUCT FOREIGN KEY(ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID_PRODUCT)
 );

CREATE TABLE MATERIAL(
      ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL NUMBER(6,0),
      PRODUCTION NUMBER(3,0),
      ID_MATERIAL NUMBER(6,0), 
      CONSTRAINT PK_MATERIAL PRIMARY KEY(ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL, ID_MATERIAL),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT FOREIGN KEY (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID_PRODUCT),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTION FOREIGN KEY (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL) REFERENCES PRODUCTION(ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_MATERIAL) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID_PRODUCT)
     );

 INSERT INTO PRODUCT (ID_PRODUCT,NAME,WEIGHT,PRICE) VALUES (1,'PRODUCT A',10,5),
 (2,'PRODUCT B',10,5),
 (3,'PRODUCT C',10,5),
 (4,'PRODUCT D',10,5),
 (5,'PRODUCT E',10,5),
 (6,'PRODUCT F',10,5),
 (7,'PRODUCT G',10,5),
 (8,'PRODUCT H',10,5),
 (9,'PRODUCT I',10,5),
 (10,'PRODUCT J',10,5)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT (ID_PRODUCT_PRODUCTION,PRODUCTION) VALUES (1,2),
(2,1),
(3,1)

INSERT INTO MATERIAL (ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL, PRODUCTION, ID_MATERIAL) VALUES (1,2,2),
(1,2,3),
(1,2,4),
(2,1,9),
(2,1,10),
(3,1,8)
```

Comment: Tentou com "CONNECT BY" ?

Comment: Tentei, mas não se fiz da maneira correta. Como seria com "CONNECT BY"?

Comment: eu pensei em criar uma procedure com loop para buscar na coluna ID_MATERIAL se ele existe na coluna ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL. Mas não sei bem como fazer.

Comment: Creio que seria algo como SELECT * FROM MATERIAL M CONNECT BY PRIOR ID_MATERIAL = ID_PRODUCT_MATERIAL , teria a hierarquia como materiais

Comment: @LucianoAmaro qual banco de dados você está utilizando? Pelo erro acredito que seja Oracle

Comment: @TiedtTech exatamente é oracle

Comment: caso eu queira retorna apenas 1 nível. Tem como fazer com um subselect? Como ficaria?

Comment: @LucianoAmaro não consegui te ajudar ontem, mas vou tentar te ajudar. Como você deseja a saida?

Comment: @ da forma como coloquei acima a tabela, talvez como os materiais dos materiais do produto na frente